# Search for a specific value in xml file and get the whole block c#

Tags: c#, xml

In the hunt for a smart solution to store values & have them presented when I want I looked over a couple of solution & thought XML files would be the easiest.

However after being able to add/load value from them I now need to extract certain values out of it for specific occasions.

To my problem~

[image: 1]

If I for an example type "A" in the left field I want it to present 10 in the field right next to it.
So

```
If textbox1.text = A(<Leftfield>) 
-  textbox2.text(rightfield) = 10.
```

XML:

```
<f1>
    <Leftfield>A</Leftfield>
    <Rightfield>10</Rightfield>
</f1>
```

Hopefully i've explained it good enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your actual question? How to select the `Rightfield` element which has a sibling `Leftfield` with a value of "A"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: you may add c# code so we can see what your progress is on the matter. For Xml you can use LINQToXml (examples @ http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples)

Comment: Load each group of `f1` into a `Dictionary<string, string>` so that you could perform a lookup: `string field2Text = (myDictionary.ContainsKey(txtField1.Text)) ? myDictionary[txtField1.Text] : string.Empty;`

Comment: If the user types A in the left field, i want it so that textbox 2 get's the value of 10. Read from the XML file. I've tried to read the F1 table and ignore the Leftfield & just in a simple if statement with no success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your XML loaded into an `XDocument` you could try something like this:

```
var rightfieldElement = xDocument.Descendants("f1").Single(x => (string)x.Element("Leftfield") == "A").Element("Rightfield");
```

That will select the `Rightfield` element which has a `Leftfield` sibling with a value of "A".

Not knowing much about your XML schema means this is quite simplistic (and could cause null reference exceptions if you don't have a matching `Leftfield` element) but it should point you in the right direction and doing some reading on LINQ yourself will improve your knowledge.

In future, it is also best to actually try it first and post the code that you've attempted.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i've never used XML before for anything, thanks!

Comment: @Hajpz If this is a good answer for you, please accept it as such.